# SQL firebird YTD except current month

Tags: sql, firebird

I'm trying to get the dates of year to date excluding the current month.

I tried the method bellow but it is very slow.

```sql
SELECT MYDATE FROM TB WHERE

(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM (MYDATE))=EXTRACT(YEAR FROM (CURRENT_DATE)) AND 
                                 EXTRACT(MONTH FROM (MYDATE))<EXTRACT(MONTH FROM (MYDATE)))
```

Is there a faster method to get the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-- Pull every "mydate" between Jan 1 of this year and the last day of
-- the previous month, inclusive
SELECT mydate
  FROM tb
 WHERE mydate BETWEEN (
              CAST(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE) || '-01-01' AS DATE)
              AND
              DATEADD(DAY, -EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURRENT_DATE), CURRENT_DATE);
```

The above will perform the boundary computation once (for the `WHERE` clause), whereas your initial query would convert/EXTRACT on every row of the table.  In theory, the above is faster.  In practice, unless you have a huge number of rows and pathologically bad database conditions, I doubt you'll notice a difference.

Comment: Hi, the SQL in fact it is much faster compared to the one I was using. I just had to add 1 to the end of the code because it was not getting the 28/02 : DATEADD(DAY, -(EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURRENT_DATE) + 1), CURRENT_DATE +1);  Now it fits my need. Thank you.

Comment: Ah of course — it’ll be easier and more readable just to drop the +1 from the second operand to DATEADD.  It’s perhaps bad form but I’ll edit the answer now…